# algorithm2e split over several pages

Tags: page-breaking, algorithm2e

Is there an option in `algorithm2e` to split the algorithm over several pages? Please no answer with "use `algorithmic` or `listings` packages". `algorithm2e` is the best package for algorithms in latex, so I want to get it running with this package.

Comment: “algorithm2e is the best package for algorithms in latex” – actually, *no*; it’s definitely not. `algorithmicx` (note the trailing “x”!) is far superior

Comment: Also a package which has "2e" in its name to indicate that it is for LaTeX2e and not for LaTeX2.x gives me the impression that it is rather old. (@Konrad)

Answer (score 15):

From the `algorithm2e` documentation:

> Caution: algorithms cannot be cut

You could use instead the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package which offers you improved functionality and offers the possibility of breaking long algorithms (see Section 2.6 *Breaking up long algorithms* of the package documentation).

Comment: Not much better though, it still requires you to manually break the algorithm block. Could mean massive reflow of your document.

Comment: `algorithmicx` hasn't been maintained since 2005! `algorithm2e` however is still active (check CTAN), so in my view it is the best package available.

Answer (score 10):

A workaround for the problem is to find good place to break,
split the algorithm, and use the next to

```
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{20}
```

The problem with embedded blocks could be solved with invisible begins/ends.
The Begin keyword can be hidden by:

```
\SetKwBlock{Begin}{}{end}
```

Example:

The first part:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\LinesNumbered
% This is to hide end and get the last vertical line straight
\SetKwBlock{Begin}{Begin}{}
\SetAlgoLined
\Begin{
% This is to restore vline mode
  \SetAlgoVlined
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
```

The second part:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \LinesNumbered
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{19}
%This is to hide Begin keyword
\SetKwBlock{Begin}{}{end}
\Begin{
```

Update the example code:

```
    \documentclass{report}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
\LinesNumbered
% This is to hide end and get the last vertical line straight
\SetKwBlock{Begin}{Begin}{}
\SetAlgoLined
  \Begin{
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}


\SetNlSty{texttt}{(}{)}
\begin{algorithm}
  \LinesNumbered
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{12}
% This is to restore vline mode if you did not take the package as \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
  \SetAlgoVlined
%This is to hide Begin keyword
\SetKwBlock{Begin}{}{end}
\Begin{
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
  $\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \emptyset$\;     
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds easy... how about providing an example that does this? The example should include nested blocks of pseudo-code and the algorithm broken across these nested blocks.

Comment: Probably, an example will obscure the simplicity of the solution.

Comment: How would you manage the case where there is a `\caption` added to the algorithm under the `ruled` style?

Comment: Depends on what I want to achieve. Probably I don't see the problem. I would call parts like "Algorithm (Part 1 of 3)" etc...

Comment: (+1) this worked best for me.