# pseudo code with vertical line

Tags: algorithmicx

I want to write some pseudo code. After few research I found algorithmicx with this post: [Write pseudo code in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768/write-pseudo-code-in-latex)

But I want vertical line as this:

```
function toto: 
| for i = 0 , i < 10, i++ 
|  | print i * i = i^2 
|  | if i is a prime number 
|  |  | print prime number 
|  | end if 
|  end for 
end function
```

According to the documentation the package does not provide this (or I missed it)

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with `algorithmicx`, but you can with [`algorithm2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e).

Comment: I can use algorithm2e instead of algorithmicx so it's perfect

Comment: As jubobs said algorithm2e package can do it: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No package needed except `fontenc` for setting things like `<` properly.  Parameters `\lindent`, `\rthk`, and `\rindent` control the space to the left of the rule, the rule thickness, and the space to the right of the rule, respectively.

After several failed attempts to allow special characters, I decided that for pseudo code, you might be able to survive without the use of special characters.  The macro I introduce is `\block{pre\\code}{indented\\code}{post\\code}`.

EDITED to `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip`, so that `%` are not needed everywhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\lindent{.5ex}
\def\rindent{2ex}
\def\rthk{1.5pt}
\newcommand\block[3]{\unskip%
  \noindent\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\strut\ignorespaces#1\strut}\\
  \setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\strut\ignorespaces#2\strut}}%
  \hspace*{\lindent}\rule[-.5\dp\strutbox]{\rthk}{\ht0}\hspace{\rindent}\box0\\%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\strut\ignorespaces#3\strut}%
\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\block{
function toto:\\
setup
}{
  \block{
  for i = 0 , i < 10, i++
  }{
    \block{
    if i is a prime number
    }{
      print prime number\\
      then do something else
    }{
    end if
    }\\
    some intermediate stuff\\
    \block{
    if i is a superprime number
    }{
      print superprime number\\
      then really do something amazing
    }{
    end if
    }
  }{
  end for
  }
}{
finish up\\
end function
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The good thingss with your solution is the possibility to have a lot of kind of exotic loop or name if you want to change it. Really interesting

Answer (score 2):

As jubobs said algorithm2e package can do it:

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{None}
\KwResult{None}
\for{i = 0, i < 10, i++}{
    print i * i
    \eIf{i is a prime number}
        {Prime number}
        {Not a prime number}
}
\end{algorithm}
```