# Object-oriented class typesetting?

Tags: listings, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am looking for a way to beautifully typeset an OO class like :

```
classname 
{
     properties:
         prop1 : integer
         prop2 : Node

     methods:
         someMethod()
}
```

With the look & feel of `algorithm2e` algorithms. (i.e. not code-looking like `listings`).

Is there any package already doing this or should I roll my own way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `algorithm2e` is really unwarranted, here. After all, your class is *not* an algorithm. `listings` is a more natural choice and is perfectly capable of beautifully typesetting it. Why insist on using `algorithm2e` instead of `listings`?

Comment: I don't insist on using `algorithm2e`, but I want it to look like something more "theoretical" than something inside `listings` (because my algorithms are typeset using alg2e). For instance, bold font for keywords, no typewriter-style fonts...

Comment: By "theoretical", do you mean that you're explaining the syntax of class definition to your readers?

Comment: No, I mean that it's not in an existing programming language, it's only pseudo-code.

Comment: Here's one possibility: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172981/pseudo-code-with-vertical-line/173011#173011.  The other way is to use a verbatim-type environment but make the font `\rmfamily` instead of `\ttfamily`.