# Indentation marker for listings

Tags: listings, sourcecode

I'm currently writing a document that contains several code samples. I included them as lstlistings and played around with the colors and everything, so they loot quite nice now. My only problem is that in bigger code blocks it gets quite hard to keep track of the indentations, so I'd like to have those vertical lines that many IDEs and text editors have. Is there a way of including those automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) show an example of such a listing we can play with and an indication what symbols and positions you would regard as acceptable markers.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is commonly employed in so-called psuedo-code (e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172981/pseudo-code-with-vertical-line).  But I gather you are looking for an auto implementation into `listings`?